# How Do I Design Abstract Semantic Graphs?

Tags: language-design

Can someone direct me to online resources for designing and implementing abstract semantic graphs (ASG)? I want to create an ASG editor for my language.  Being able to edit the ASG directly has a number of advantages:

1. Only identifiers and literals need to be typed in and identifiers are written only once, when they're defined. Everything else is selected via the mouse.
2. Since the editor knows the language's grammar, there are no more syntax errors. The editor prevents them from being created in the first place.
3. Since the editor knows the language's semantics, there are no more semantic errors.

There are some secondary advantages:

1. Since all the reserved words are easily separable, a program can be written in one locale and viewed in other. On-the-fly changes of locale are possible.
2. All the text literals are easily separable, so changes of locale are easily made, including on-the-fly changes.

Comment: You might consider looking at bigraphs as well.

Comment: Dude, you had tha same idea that i had a few days ago. Maybe we could team up and do something cool!

Comment: But concerning to the editor experience, I was thinking the oposite. I thought of a modal Structure Editor that would allow me avoid mouse usage and be productive at the same time, because I wouldn't need to navigate character by character, but word by word and easily wrap or unwrap code with some keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a book on the matter, but you'll find the topic discussed in portions of various books on computer language.  You'll also find discussions of this surrounding various projects which implement what you describe.  For instance, you'll find quite a bit of discussion regarding the design of [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/).  Most workflow engines are also based on scripting in semantic graphs.

Allow me to opine...  We've had the technology to manipulate language structurally for basically as long as we've had programming languages.  I believe that the reason we still use textual language is a combination of the fact that it is more natural for us as humans, who communicate in natural language, to wield, and the fact that it is sometimes difficult to compose and refactor code when proper structure has to be maintained.  If you're not sure what I mean, try building complex expressions in Scratch.  Text is easier and a decent IDE gives virtually as much verification of correct structure.*

*I don't mean to take anything away from Scratch, it's a thing of beauty and is perfect for its intended purpose.

Comment: I disagree. The reason we use "language" for programming is because imperative programming is easy to learn.

Comment: @Shawnhcorey:  The question I was raising and self-answering is why we still program primarily in text rather than diagrammatically.  I'm not sure I understand the gist of your assertion, as one can program imperatively diagrammatically as well, which is the matter of discussion.  I also assert that the syntax isn't necessarily easy to learn as is evidenced by the fact that Scratch, a language without a textual syntax, is positioned as a learning language.

Comment: We programming in text because text is sequential. We are used to learn procedures a step at a time: do this; then this; then this.... Diagrammatic programming is confusing. To understand a diagram, you don't comprehend it all at once. You follow a path through it. Then another path. Then another. You are (tediously) learning the diagram using by learning the procedures of its different branches. That's why text is the preferred way to program today, some 50 years after it started. Diagrammatic programming has been experimented with but has not caught on.